# Do I use Fortran system_clock correctly?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, system-clock

I am using the function `system_clock` with Fortran90 (compiled with gfortran) in the following way :

```
   ! Variables for clock
   integer count_0, count_1
   integer count_rate, count_max
   double precision time_init, time_final, elapsed_time

   ! Starting time
   call system_clock(count_0, count_rate, count_max)
   time_init = count_0*1.0/count_rate

   .... Main code

   ! Ending time
   call system_clock(count_1, count_rate, count_max)
   time_final = count_1*1.0/count_rate
   ! Elapsed time
   elapsed_time = time_final - time_init

   ! Write elapsed time
   write(*,1003) int(elapsed_time),elapsed_time-int(elapsed_time)

1003 format('  Wall Clock = ',i0,f0.9)
```

I would like to know if I use correctly this function. Indeed, I didn't specify a value for `count_rate` and `count_max` but I guess there are default values. Moreover, It seems that I have to take into account the case where `count_0` or `count_1` are over `count_max` values, doesn't it. As you can see, for pretty formatting, I have split the seconds and the decimal part of elapsed time.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Did you encounter any problem? Was there any error message? Are the results wrong or correct?

Comment: `count_0` and `count_1` will never be greater than `count_max`.

Comment: For GFortran specific information about SYSTEM_CLOCK, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM_005fCLOCK.html

Comment: Also note that all the arguments to SYSTEM_CLOCK are INTENT(OUT). Which means that the intrinsic will never read from the arguments, only overwrite whatever was there before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks correct from reading. However it is very difficult to find out correctness of any code without seeing the output.

I recommend using larger integers (`integer(int64)`). `int64` is defined in module `iso_fortran_env`, in Fortran 90 you can use `selected_int_kind`. It is compiler specific, but you are likely to get higher `count_max` and finer `count_rate` with larger integers. At least that happens for common compilers like gfortran and Intel.

I don't think you can monitor `count` and compare it with `count_max` usefully. And I never had the need when I used the larger integers as shown above. I can imagine some way (comparing with `count_max/2`), but it would be clumsy. You cannot restart the counter anyway.

What you can do is to write a small program that will print the maximum times

```
use iso_fortran_env, only: int32, int64, real64

integer(int32) :: count_max, count_rate

call system_clock(count_max=count_max, count_rate=count_rate)

write(*,*) "Maximum time:", real(count_max, real64) / count_rate

end
```

Try both `integer(int32)` and `integer(int64)` and also just `integer` above and observe the maximum times possible with those choices for your compiler.

For me with gfortran on Linux x86_64 the 32-bit integers give me almost 25 days of maximum time, while the 64-bit integers allow 292 years. The clock resolution is much finer with 64-bit integers too (1 ms vs. 1 ns).

Comment: -@Vladimir F: the code seems to give correct runtimes, I just wanted to get validation for a righ use of this function. My maximum runtimes are equal to few hours (approximately between 1 and 2 hours). I am going to see the `count_max' value with int32 and int64. Regards

Comment: It is normally almost impossible to guarantee correctness of any non-trivial code. But the call looks to be correct.